# Jquery audio player volume automation. Calculating the volume position between two points

Tags: jquery, math, equation

I am trying to implement 'volume automation' in a jQuery audio player I have built.

As you can see form the picture below I have a line graph overlayed which has draggable points.

While the audio is playing an event fires every second (currently, I may up the frequency if needed) which collects the data.

The data I am returning is the audio position and the volume (determined from the height of the 'point'... not the line itself.

This means that currently despite a slope being rendered the volume only changes when each individual point is reached in the song. (a point being a single 'dot' on the line.

[image]

I have chosen to do it this way performance reasons.

However, using this method means that I need to perform a calculation to work out the volume inbetween the points.

Math really is not my strong point and I can remember very little from my school days.

I am storing the variables currently as:-

- x0 = Last point position
- x1 = next point position
- y0 = Last point
- y1 = next point
- position = current position in  seconds

I hope the above makes sense!

If I remember correctly the equation needed is something to do with calculating the difference between the two points, so I assume this would just need a simple equation using the contents of the above variables.

The volume scale is 0-100.  Therefore obiously a point at the top of the waveform should have a volume value of 100 and a point at the bottom should have a volume value of 0.  With the individual points inbetween being calculated by the required equation.

If anyone can shed any light on this matter or help point me towards a solution It would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to find the volume(y) between two points?  As in (position - x0) * (y1 - y0) + y0?

Note that that is simplified based on the given that x0 and x1 are 1 unit apart.

Full detail:

Find slope: slope = (y1-y0)/(x1-x0)

Find % we are between x0 and x1: distance = (position - x0) / (x1 - x0)

slope * distance will give us the change thus far:  change = slope * distance

To find the new value, add the change to the last value:  y position = change + y0;

Re-substituting all the variables gives us:
y0 + ( ((y1 - y0)/(x1 - x0))  * ((position - x0) / (x1 - x0)))

If you're sample is at 1 unit, you can leave out the (x1 - x0) term.

Comment: Perfect exactly what I needed.  A great simple answer thank you.